# How to perform almost the same query N times without rewriting it N times?

Tags: union

Basically I have a list of numbers like:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

And I want to perform a query like this for each of the previous numbers:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), field_name
FROM my_table
WHERE field_name = NUMBER
```

Where "NUMBER" will be 1, 2 ... 5 in this example. So I expect a result containing 5 rows and 2 columns.

Right now I'm doing the task this way:

```
(SELECT ... field_name = 1) UNION (SELECT ... field_name = 2 ) ... (SELECT ... field_name = 5)
```

Is there any alternative way to do this while still using a single query? In particularly I don't like how the last query may become very long as my list of numbers grows.

*-----EDIT-----*

What if the query to execute would be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE field_name > NUMBER
```

Using the same mechanism as above but this time let's image that this query will return more than 1 row at every execution.

Is there any way to create a single, elegant, query to do this job instead of using "UNION" multiple times?

Comment: For performance you would be better using `UNION ALL` as `UNION` will try to remove duplicate rows, even if they don't exist in your actual data.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about this.

Comment: Your edit makes no sense. You can use what the answer provided, `SELECT COUNT(*), field_name FROM my_table WHERE field_name > NUMBER GROUP BY field_name ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IN` statement

```
SELECT COUNT(*), field_name
FROM MY_table
WHERE field_name IN (1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY field_name
```

Comment: Actually I can't, it produces different results. In my test case all the "COUNT(*)"s were summed for example.

Comment: `GROUP BY` ....

Comment: Add "GROUP BY field_name" to the above example and you should get the result you desire.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the GROUP BY field_name. That should work

Comment: Great, it works for my test example! But how can I do it if my example query doesn't return just one row but more than one? As far as I can see if I GROUP BY the "field_name" only one row will be returned for each number in the list.

Comment: So are there other fields in these tables?

Comment: @Fabio, I'm having difficulty seeing how your sample query *could* return more than one row.  You have a predicate on `field_name` and an un-qualified `COUNT()`.  Can you edit your question to elaborate, please?

Comment: @Michael, I've edited my post to better explain my second question.

Comment: So now you are not using a COUNT? If so just remove the GROUP BY